# Number of ideals with norm equals to a certain number in number field.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

I can't follow the claim in the lecture notes below about the number of ideals with norm $n$. Any help or hint is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meant $n^k$. If $N(I)=p^k$ then $I$ is a product of at most $k$ prime ideals of norm a power of $p$ and there are at most $n$ of those.

If $p$ splits completely then the exact number is ${n+k-1 \choose k}$ (a combination with repetition).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I can see what you mean, but my text is saying something stronger. I've updated the question to include the quote from the text. Could you have a look?

Comment: It is a mistake. There is nothing stronger than ${n+k-1 \choose k}$ because it is the exact number when $p$ splits completely, that is the best upper bound for $p,K$ arbitrary and $n$ a power of $p$. And $a_n$ is multiplicative. Which book ?

Comment: It's a lecture notes that I don't think was published yet. I'll write to my lecturer to ask about it.

Comment: Tell him that it is immediate that the coefficients of $\zeta_K(s)$ are bounded by those of $\zeta(s)^{[K:Q]}$ and at the $a_n$ with $n$ a product of unramified primes it is an equality.

Comment: It is confirmed that what's in the note is a mistake. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I meant $n$ a product of primes splitting completely, sorry for the typo